# Regex detect last character slash and and ?id=

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my Javascript regex `^.*(?<!\/)$` that checks if the URL is not ending with (/) slash

detects: `/play/popular`
ok: `/play/popular/`

How can I detect if the URL is not ending with `/` and does not include `?id=` ?

detects: `play/popular`
catch: `play/popular/?id=448`

debugger: https://regex101.com/r/sSDIic/2

Comment: Why not parse the URL and check that way instead of throwing regex at it?

Comment: This may be an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/289905). You can parse any URL with the [`URL` API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL), e.g. given `const url = new URL("https://example.com/play/popular/?id=448");`, `url.pathname` is `"/play/popular/"`, `url.searchParams.get("id")` is `"448"`. It shouldn’t matter if the URL has an extra slash at the end or not. In what context is this check being done?

Comment: What about `/play/popular?id=448` should this match?

Comment: I am using some Nuxt redirect plugins that automatically redirecting URLs without slashes
`{from: '^.*(?<!\/)$',to: (from, req) => req.url + '/',statusCode: 301}`
That's why I need regex
@Barmar no its ok

Comment: Can there be other parameters, like `/play/popular/?id=448&name=abc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to extend the negative lookbehind to optionally add the `id=` followed by 1 or more digits.

```
^.*$(?<!\/(?:\?id=\d+)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Pc2Ys/1)

It might be easier to rule out `id=` in the string using a negative lookahead, and match a non whitespace char at the end being not a `/`if it can not end on a space.

```
^(?!.*\?id=).*[^\s/]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JCdKEa/1)

Note that `.*` also match spaces, to match only non whitespace characters you can use `\S*`

Comment: That's what I wanted, `^(?!.*\?id=).*[^\s/]$` 
Thank you